# Infinity as parameter?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've been reading through the Underscore library source code, and came across this:

```
  _.iteratee = builtinIteratee = function(value, context) {
    return cb(value, context, Infinity);
  };
```

What does it mean to have `Infinity` as a parameter?

Edit:

Sorry, here is `cb` and `optimizeCb`. They transform callbacks into the appropriate iteratees.

```
  var optimizeCb = function(func, context, argCount) {
    if (context === void 0) return func;
    switch (argCount) {
      case 1: return function(value) {
        return func.call(context, value);
      };
      // The 2-parameter case has been omitted only because no current consumers
      // made use of it.
      case null:
      case 3: return function(value, index, collection) {
        return func.call(context, value, index, collection);
      };
      case 4: return function(accumulator, value, index, collection) {
        return func.call(context, accumulator, value, index, collection);
      };
    }
    return function() {
      return func.apply(context, arguments);
    };
  };

  // An internal function to generate callbacks that can be applied to each
  // element in a collection, returning the desired result — either `identity`,
  // an arbitrary callback, a property matcher, or a property accessor.
  var cb = function(value, context, argCount) {
    if (_.iteratee !== builtinIteratee) return _.iteratee(value, context);
    if (value == null) return _.identity;
    if (_.isFunction(value)) return optimizeCb(value, context, argCount);
    if (_.isObject(value) && !_.isArray(value)) return _.matcher(value);
    return _.property(value);
  };
```

Comment: Depends, what does `cb()` do?

Comment: it means whatever `cb` is (you haven't shown) will be called with the third argument being `Infinity` ... whatever `cb` is (did I mention you haven't shown that) does with `Infinity` whatever it needs to do with `Infinity`

Comment: It doesn't mean anything special, `Infinity` is just another number, with certain properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Infinity` is interpreted as a number. In this case, the source leads here:

```
  // Internal function that returns an efficient (for current engines) version
  // of the passed-in callback, to be repeatedly applied in other Underscore
  // functions.
  var optimizeCb = function(func, context, argCount) {
    if (context === void 0) return func;
    switch (argCount == null ? 3 : argCount) {
      case 1: return function(value) {
        return func.call(context, value);
      };
      // The 2-argument case is omitted because we’re not using it.
      case 3: return function(value, index, collection) {
        return func.call(context, value, index, collection);
      };
      case 4: return function(accumulator, value, index, collection) {
        return func.call(context, accumulator, value, index, collection);
      };
    }
    return function() {
      return func.apply(context, arguments);
    };
  };
```

Notice that `Infinity` is passed to the parameter `argCount`. The switch/case statement will exit and return a function that will simply apply the context and arguments to the callback function. Using `Infinity` seems to ensure the fall-through case.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. So it's basically saying personalized iteratees accommodate whatever parameters the users wants. So I guess the user just remove s `builtInIteratee` from the assignment and the iteratee is now custom.

Answer (score 1):

It means that parameter is greater than all other numbers for all intents and purposes:

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity):

> The initial value of Infinity is Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY. The value Infinity (positive infinity) is greater than any other number. Mathematically, this value behaves the same as infinity; for example, any positive number multiplied by Infinity equals Infinity, and any number divided by Infinity equals 0.